# How can I tell MATLAB that the data I am importing is a series of vectors, not just a series of letters?

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, vector

I have obtained my data using python for a project in MATLAB. I have 3 different matrices of dimensions mxn, mxn+1 and mxn+2. I used this command in python `scipy.io.savemat('set1.mat', mdict ={'abc1':abc1})`. Each row of the matrix should actually be a row of row vectors (of length p) not scalars, so that the matrices are actually `mx(n)*p`, `mx(n+1)*p` and `mx(n+2)*p`.

As an example, I have defined at the top of the MATLAB file for both cases

```
A = ones(1,5)
B = 2*ones(1,5)
C = 3*ones(1,5)
```

Now directly in MATLAB I can write:

```
abc1 = [A B C]
```

which strange as though it may seem, gives me the output I want.

```
abc1 =    
Columns 1 through 14    
     1     1     1     1     1     2     2     2     2     2     3     3     3     3
Column 15    
     3
```

Now if I import my data using load I can grab `abc1(1,:)`. This gives me:

```
ans = A B C
```

or I could take:

```
abc1(1,1)    
ans = A
```

How can I get it to recognise that A is the name of a vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand of your question it sounds like you have (in matlab):

```
A = ones(1,5);
B = 2*ones(1,5);
C = 3*ones(1,5);

load('set1.mat');
```

And then you want to do something like:

```
D = [abc1];
```

and have the result be, for `abc1 = 'A B C'`, the equivalent of `[A B C]`.

There are a number of options for doing this. The first and possibly simplest is to use eval, though I shudder to mention it, since most consider [eval to be evil](http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#Why_is_it_advised_to_avoid_using_the_.22eval.22_function.3F).

In your case this would look like:

```
D = eval(['[' abc1 ']']);
```

A nicer solution would be to exploit the [dynamic field names](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html) trick that can be done with structures:

```
foo.A = ones(1,5);
foo.B = 2*ones(1,5);
foo.C = 3*ones(1,5);

load('set1.mat'); 

D = [foo.(abc1(1,1)) foo.(abc1(1,2)) foo.(abc1(1,3))];
```

Or, if you need to concatenate more than just 3 columns you could do so itteratively, using the [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) function. e.g.:

```
D = [];
for idx = 1:3
    D = cat(2, D, foo.(abc1(1,idx)));
end
```

Or, if you know the length of D before you have created it you can use a slightly more efficient version:

```
D = zeros(1, num_elements);
ins_idx = 1;
for idx = 1:3
    temp_num = length(foo.(abc1(1,idx)));
    D(ins_idx:(ins_idx+temp_num-1)) = foo.(abc1(1,idx));
    ins_idx = ins_idx + temp_num;
end
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. This foo solution works as is. The only problem is, I asked the question using a simplified example of my project. There are around 30,000 data entries so writing "D" like this would take a lot of time and space on the script. I will try manipulating what you have shown me, but I'm just waiting for some slightly amended data to come through so I can do this. In the meantime, do you have any suggestions for how to load so much data more succinctly?

Comment: I have added some alternative examples of how to write "D", which might help.

Answer (score 0):

Load the data into a structure and use dynamic field indexing:

```
s = load('yourfile');
s.(abc1(1,1))
```

However, if you keep structuring your project in the above-mentioned way, you're probably gonna run into `eval()`, which I always suggest to avoid.